# Which is better: setcookie("name", "value") or localStorage.setItem("key","value")?

Tags: javascript, php, save, setcookie

I want to create a save functionality for my website, but I can't decide whether to use:

```
<?php
setcookie("save","100");
?>
```

OR

```
<script>
localStorage.setItem("save","100");
</script>
```

Ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local Storage vs Cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)